# VMware Server directory

Tags: vmware-server

Where does VMware Server store VMs?

I want to add an existing VM to VMware Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
C:\Virtual Machines
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific place. Open up the console, go to File->New, to create a new VM, and select "custom" when it asks you what settings. Then it will ask you where you want to put the files.

Answer (score 0):

It a linux file system, that you interface with over the network with the virtual converter and infrasturcture client

you can use the converter to 'convert' existing machines to/upload to the VMWare server

They are stored in a file store, which looks like a drive but isn't
By default its called the DataStore (if multiple exist, datastore 1....2...3..)

You can also connect an iscsi capable datastore and use that to hold vm machines
it needs to be formatted though for it to use it